# Gitlab API POST new issue

Tags: post, gitlab

[image]

I encountered an error sending Gitlab issue

"error": "labels is invalid"

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the label first, then you submit a label by its name.

**Create Label:**
`POST https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/labels`

```
{
   "name": "label_name",
   "color": "#000000"
}
```

**Create Issue:**
`POST https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/issues`

```
{
   "name": "issue_name",
   "description": "issue_desc",
   "labels": "label_name"
}
```

In case you want to set more than one label you need to set the labels as comma separated string:

```
{
   "name": "issue_name",
   "description": "issue_desc",
   "labels": "label1,label2"
}
```